# I wish to inquire whether there is any kind of magnet that can be used to push away a metal other than attract!

Tags: electromagnetism

I wish to inquire whether there is any kind of magnet that can be used to push away a metal other than attract it.. or what can be done to create eddy currents that can do that!

Comment: when north meets north, it repels. so two pieces of magnetized metal repel  if they have the same pole facing each other

Comment: You can repel bismuth with a strong enough magnet.  It's strongly [diamagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism).

Comment: Read about [Magnetic Levitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_levitation).

Comment: thanks.  so,  is there a magnet that can stop a moving body eg a car or slower its speed from outside?

Answer (score 2):

Many metals are pushed away from a magnet because they are diamagnetic which means that they have a negative magnetic susceptibility $\chi=\mu-1$ (or a magnetic permeability smaller than 1). Compared to ferromagnetism, this effect is, however, very small and can only be seen in high magnetic fields. Examples are the metals copper, lead, silver, bismuth, antimony. Superconductors are perfectly diamagnetic with $\chi=-1$. See [Diamagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism)

Answer (score 0):

An Eddy Current separator can be used to remove non-ferrous metals from a stream of waste that has already been cleansed of ferrous metals.

First, an *ordinary magnet* operates conventionally to lift ferrous waste from the stream.

Then, a *varying magnetic field* is applied to the cleansed waste stream.  This can be a rotating permanent magnet or an electromagnet driven by alternating current.  This changing magnetic field induces eddy currents in a conductor; the current generates a magnetic field that opposes the applied field.  The conductor is repelled and separates from the waste stream...